# Nginx Proxy Pass File with Extensions

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have the following config:

```
location /api/ {        
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

it works, except not for any path with an extension, ie .html or .txt.

tried

```
location ~ ^/api/(.*) {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/$1;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }
```

but that results in 502 bad gateway.

tried removing the trailing slash but results in 404s to the proxied server.  is there a simple way to make it work, WITH extensions?

I also have this later on which may be conflicting?

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```